# How to handle several instance on the same Class in a plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, es6-class

I have a JS plugin using es6 class syntax. I'm not sure on the way to handle several instances of the class versus once instance with a several element inside.
This plugin can have an array an unlimited number of image nodes as parameters.

This is the class syntax I have so far

```
(function(window) {

    function handle(element, options) {
        let handles = [];
        if (element.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                handles.push(new Plugin(element[i], options));
            }
        } else {
            handles.push(new Plugin(element, options));
        }
        return handles;
    }

    class Plugin {
        constructor(element, options) {
            this.element = element;
            this.init();
        }

        init() {
            //get its translated value
            this.methodA();

            //apply its translation even if not visible for the first init
            this.methodB();
        }

        methodA() {
            this.element.classList.add('test');
        }

    }

    return handle;
});
```

I would like to get rid of this handle function. What is the other way to have an instance of plugin for every element? and to be able to have the classPlugin at the top level without the need for this handle function.

I don't see any other way that having several instances of the class, because each instance get specified info for each image (height, offset, etc). Maybe I am missing something obvious here...

Comment: You need a loop somewhere to create all the instances. Beyond that we don't know enough about how this is used

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually instantiate an instance of a class without a loop. You may try `eval`. But it's not recommended. It's a bad practice. 
Now let me explain why it is not possible. 
JavaScript does not have classes and instances, it has only objects, which can delegate to other objects.

To create two objects based on a single object, but behind the scenes, there aren’t really two ‘instances’ of the Point object, there are just two objects that delegate to the original one. When you use new, JavaScript is actually just creating an object and setting its prototype to the object returned by the constructor function. Imagine if the example had been expanded to include a shared method like this:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Point.prototype.logCoords = function () {
    console.log(this.x, this.y);
};

var a = new Point(1, 2);
console.log(a.x); // logs '1'
a.logCoords(); // logs '1 2'
```

Behind the scenes, what’s happening is something more like this:

```
var Point = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Point.prototype.logCoords = function () {
    console.log(this.x, this.y);
};

var a = {};
a.__proto__ = Point.prototype; // see note below about this
a.constructor = Point;
a.constructor(1, 2);

console.log(a.x); // logs '1'
a.logCoords(); // logs '1 2'
```